# How to find x-identity & x-signature in Bitpay (docs)

Tags: php, laravel, curl, helper

I'm integrating bitpay in my project
but when i hit api "https://test.bitpay.com/invoices" it give response { error : "Invalid-Signature" }

https://bitpay.com/api/#rest-api-resources-invoices-create-an-invoice

```
$resourceUrl = 'https://test.bitpay.com/invoices';

$postData = json_encode([
   'currency' => 'EUR',
   'price' => 10,
   'orderId' => 'MerchantOrder123',
   'fullNotifications' => true,
   'extendedNotifications' => true,
   'transactionSpeed' => 'medium',
   'notificationURL' => 'https://yournotificationurl.com',
   'notificationEmail' => 'merchant@email.com',
   'redirectURL' => 'https://yourredirecturl.com',
   'buyer' => [
       'email' => 'fox.mulder@trustno.one',
       'name' => 'Fox Mulder',
       'phone' => '555-123-456',
       'address1' => '2630 Hegal Place',
       'address2' => 'Apt 42',
       'locality' => 'Alexandria',
       'region' => 'VA',
       'postalCode' => '23242',
       'country' => 'US',
       'notify' => true
   ],
   'posData' => 'tx1234',
   'itemDesc' => 'Item XYZ',
   'token' => '6oE1tYw1xMqUjM97dk57cwbda5sxbXTkUgg7UKpwkzEE'
]);

$curlCli = curl_init($resourceUrl);

curl_setopt($curlCli, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curlCli, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
   'x-accept-version: 2.0.0',
   'Content-Type: application/json',
   'x-identity: 02e6228330bb3f4887ec4eb650dc52d668172a7de39076281e030c03bba10bd8a6',
   'x-signature: 304502207f4ee84d8d2ff46439ed3958c1b2a1c3efefba0455d5d4ce213d855075bd6353022100ccf8df1b6f1934124ddbc034fb0eddab6bba0a538919bb87a6cf5a0a8f030fda'
]);

curl_setopt($curlCli, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, stripslashes($postData));

$result = curl_exec($curlCli);
curl_close($curlCli);

echo $result;
```

Comment: How do you sign you sugnature?

Comment: the above code is from their official documentation, each params is defined but i dont find any solution